# SQL Date less than few days from today

Tags: sql, date, hsqldb, days

I have a table in which I have emails to users and I want to make request to take users who are dated less than two days from today. How can make this?
This is my SQL table :

```
CREATE TABLE vacation_users(EMAIL VARCHAR(255), STARTDATE DATE, ENDDATE DATE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this(not tested):

```
SELECT EMAIL from vacation_users 
    WHERE ENDDATE < DATEADD(day, +2, CURRENT_DATE) AND ENDDATE > CURRENT_DATE
```

It selects the mails, which have the enddate, which is equal bigger than current date, but smaller than current date + 2.

EDIT: I updated the answer, since the OP informed me about the DB, which is used. If CURRENT_DATE also doesn't work, you can try another from the [built-in functions](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/builtinfunctions-chapt.html#bfc_current_datetime).

Comment: Which database do you use?

Comment: HSQLDB database

Comment: Glad to hear that.

Comment: Your answer is good because it ignores the old dates. You need to change the remaining GETDATE() to CURRENT_DATE.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is this. I use HSQLDB and this is answer.

```
SELECT * FROM vacation_user WHERE (ENDDATE < (SYSDATE + 2 DAY));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM vacation_users 
WHERE (DATEADD(day,2,ENDDATE)) < (CONVERT(date, SYSDATETIME()))
```

Answer (score 0):

select * 
from vacation_users
where STARTDATE = dateadd(day,datediff(day,2,STARTDATE),0)

Answer (score 0):

That depends on a database you use, but the principle is more or less the same.

In Oracle, you'd do something like

```
select email
from vacation_users
where startdate < sysdate - 2;
```

which returns you to exact time 2 days ago (if it is 09:53 today, it'll be 09:53 2 days ago). Depending on what you really need, you might need to `TRUNC`ate those values (so that you'd get date without its time component) or apply some other function or principle, regarding possible index impact etc.

Though, "dated less than two days from today" is ... what exactly? Is it a `STARTDATE` or `ENDDATE` (or some combination of those two)?